# JS Script not recognized in ASP.Net Page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a dropdownlist that has chekboxs inside so you can select multiple options in an easy way. This multiselect dropdown list should be implemented using bootstrap multiselect ([link for that](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-multiselect)).

The problem I am experiencing is that the script that I use for this it is not working and I think it is because I am trying to use it in a child page and not in the master page.

**MASTER.MASTER**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="ProyectoPermanencia.Presentacion.Master" %>

            <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head runat="server">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <link href="css/MasterStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!--HERE IS A REFERENCE-->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" /> 



                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <!--HERE IS ANOTHER REFERENCE-->
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script> 




                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <title>Sistema Permanencia</title>





            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="formPrincipal" class="container-fluid body" runat="server">
                    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scrp1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

                    <!-- Header -->
                    <div class="">
                        <header>
                            <img runat="server" src="~/imgs/logo_50años_avaras_blanco_01.png" width="260" />
                        </header>
                    </div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ContentPlaceHolderTitle">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


                    <div class="container visible">
                        <div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderFicha" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolderGlobal" runat="server">
                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                        </div>


                    </div>


                </form>


            </body>
            </html>
```

**VISIONGLOBAL.ASPX** Here I want to use this dropdown list

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisionGlobal.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProyectoPermanencia.Presentacion.VisionGlobal" %>

        <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderTitle" runat="server">
            <asp:Label runat="server">
                <h3 style="color:azure"> Visión Global  </h3>
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="ContentGlobal" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderGlobal" runat="server">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="container" style="font-size: small">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="jumbotron modal-content col-md-4" style="height: 150px; padding: 5px; padding-right: 0px; box-shadow: none; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px; border-radius: 2px; border-left: 5px solid rgb(252,173,24); border-right: 5px solid rgb(252,173,24); box-shadow: none;">






    <!--THIS LIST BELOW IS THE ONE THAT SHOULD BECOME A DROPDOWN LIST WITH CHECKBOXES-->
                                    <div id="Carrera pl-1" class="col-md-3" >
                                        <div class="form row align-items-center">
                                            <h5>Carrera: </h5>
                                            <!--<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Seleccionar" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-warning ml-4" OnClientClick="ddlEscuelas_SelectedIndexChanged" />-->
                                            <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstBoxTest" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Green" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Yellow" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Black" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:ListBox>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>


                                    </div>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" BehaviorID="mpeID" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnBuscarCarreras"
                                        PopupControlID="Panel1" OkControlID="OKButton" />
                                </div>
                            </div>




                        </div>

                    <!--BELOW IS THE SCRIPT THAT SHOULD TURN THE LISTBOX INTO A DROPDOWN LIST WITH CHECKBOXES-->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $('#lstBoxTest').multiselect({
                            includeSelectAllOption:true
                        })
                    });
                </script>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </asp:Content>
```

I've been following a youtube tutorial for this [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmUZELDhy6s&t=489s) and I have even tried with other types of lists but the problem seems in how I am implementing the JS, not the "add-in" I am using.

[image: this is how the dropdown list should look like]

I have reasearched a lot but I have not found a solution for this

**EDIT**: The List is being displayed but the script is not working so I am seeing just a listbox

[image: EDIT]

Comment: There are lots of things that could be going wrong. In your browser, can you see any error messages? That will give us a clue what is going wrong. If you are using Chrome or Firefox, you can press F12 to see the developer tools, then select "Console". If there are any error messages shown, please add them to your question.

Comment: @cbp I have just edited the question, forgot to mention that I am seeing just the listbox

Comment: i think you should add css of multiselect and <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="lstBoxTest" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientMode="Static">

Comment: Nothing worked, I do not know why. Thanks everyone